# How to make a series of increasingly bigger letter L's made from asterisks?

Tags: c++

**Need to make a program with menu that has three functions in C++ using Code::Blocks:**

**1.** Exit.

**2.** Increasing numbers by 1 (Example: 1,2,3,4,5) until number specified by user.

**3.** A series of L's made with asterisks that progressively grow 1 by 1 on both sides.

[Example of what the function is supposed to print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZW8yN.png)

[Example of what the function in my program prints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOFVu.png)

**Note:** I am just starting to code, so I would *prefer* if any solutions were made using simple for's, if's, while's, etc. Thanks.

Here is the code I have right now, function 1 and 2 work, but function 3 with the asterisks obviously doesn't:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//This function prints a number starting from 1 and then adds 1.
//Example: 12345.
int Numbers()
{
    int num,n;

    cout << "Insert a number: " <<endl;
    cin >> num;

    for ( n=1; n<=num; n++)
    {
        cout << n <<endl;
    }
    cout <<endl;
}
//This function prints a series of L's made with asterisks.
//Example:
//*
//*
//***

int Asterisks()
{
    int ast,a,s;


    cout << "Insert a number higher than 3: " <<endl;
    cin >> ast;

    for ( s=3; s<ast; s++)
    {
        for ( a=0; a<s; ++a)
        {
            cout << "* " <<endl;
        }
        for ( a=0; a<s; a++)
        {
            cout << "* ";
        }
    }
    cout <<endl;
}

int main()
{
    int x=0;
    while (x!=1)
    {
        cout << "1. Exit" <<endl;
        cout << "2. Numbers" <<endl;
        cout << "3. Asterisks" <<endl;
        cin >> x;

        if (x==2)
        {
            Numbers();
        }

        if (x==3)
        {
            Asterisks();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the second 'L' on, your code appends the first asterisk to the last one of the previous 'L'. Put the `cout << endl` such that it prints a new line after each 'L':

```
for ( s=3; s<ast; s++)
{
    for ( a=0; a<s; ++a)
    {
        cout << "* " <<endl;
    }
    for ( a=0; a<s; a++)
    {
        cout << "* ";
    }
    cout <<endl;
}
```

Comment: This did it. Such a simple fix, it's the simplest problems that are the hardest to notice, thank you very much.

Comment: @Heidren one important-for-later thing to note about `endl`: It is both an end of line and a stream flush rolled up in one. That stream flush can be brutally expensive. You generally want to use a naked end of line `'\n'` and let data build up in the stream to be written later when you aren't as busy unless you really do what to make sure what you wrote makes it to the underlying media before you do anything else.